# When should I use contrast coding?

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, stata, contrasts, categorical-encoding

I have a - so I guess - a simple question: I am using Stata 13 and I am running a Tobit model to understand differences in firm performance. Among others, I am controling for firm types $T_i$- i.e. Single-Owner-Firms $SOF$vs. Multiple-Owner-Firms $MOF$.

So far I dummied $T_i$ so that $MOF=0$ and $SOF=1$. Here is why:

Given a simple relationship such as

$y_i= a + \beta_1x_i + \beta_2T_i +\beta_3x_iT_i$

We can show that

$y_i= (a + \beta_1x_i) + T_i(\beta_2+\beta_3x_i)$

The lower order coefficients $\beta_1$ shows the simple effect of $x_i$ on $y_i$ for $T_i=0$ since $y_i= (a + \beta_1x_i)$ for $T_i=0$. Similar, $\beta_2$ shows the simple effect of $T_i$ on $y_i$ since $y_i= a + T_i\beta_2$ for $x_i=0$.

Finally, and as far as I understand it, $\beta_3$ depicts how the slopes differ the firm types $T_i=0$ and $T_i=1$

However, I now got the advice to contrast code $T_i$ so that $MOF=-1$ and $SOF=1$.

I have three questions:

1. Is the interpretation scheme I put forward above correct?
2. Why and when should one use dummy and contrast (effect) coding?
3. And if I use contrast coding, how would I interpret thet resulting coefficients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, with the caveat that Tobit models have [multiple marginal effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87355/7071) and it is not clear which ones you care about here.
2. Contrast coding is typically used when you have a categorical variable with more than two levels (something like education: dropout, high school, college, and graduate) and you are interested in comparing the marginal effects to each other, not just to the omitted base level. However, with Stata's `margins, contrast` command, this is less useful than it once was. Since you only have two levels, contrast coding does not seem very useful here.

Comment: Dimitriy, can you recomend any paper/book that allows me to read up on the ways of coding catergorical data when using Tobit models?

Comment: I asked the question with a bit more precision here again: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157013/tobit-and-categorical-independent-variables

Comment: @RachelSleeps I am not aware of any books that cover this. The [UCLA site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/effect.htm) is a good resource. The Tobit is not really different from other models when it comes to this.

Comment: thanks. I am still a bit unsure. My categorical data has two levels. Is it even possible to use contrast coding here? Or does that only work when there is a group with more than two levels?